# Android EditText - E/Minikin: no font for run starting <code> length 2

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext, character, special-characters

My app reads a text file that can contain special characters. Then I set the text to an `EditText`, but for some files (with lots of special characters) it is very slow "setting" the text:

This is what it show in the logcat when it it busy "setting the text":

```
04-15 16:39:00.245 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbf0 length 2
04-15 16:39:01.349 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+fffd length 2
04-15 16:39:02.952 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbcc length 2
04-15 16:39:03.501 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+000f length 2
04-15 16:39:03.649 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbf0 length 2
04-15 16:39:06.249 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbce length 2
04-15 16:39:08.327 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbbe length 2
04-15 16:39:08.966 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+0046 length 2
04-15 16:39:09.653 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+fffd length 2
04-15 16:39:10.374 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbf0 length 2
04-15 16:39:11.231 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbf6 length 2
04-15 16:39:13.184 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbcc length 2
04-15 16:39:13.832 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbe8 length 2
04-15 16:39:13.965 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbf0 length 2
04-15 16:39:17.012 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbce length 2
04-15 16:39:19.248 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbbe length 2
04-15 16:39:19.964 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbe1 length 2
04-15 16:39:20.910 24763-24763/com.my.packagename E/Minikin: no font for run starting u+dbd2 length 2
```

I think it is trying to get the correct characters, but that operation is slow. Is there a way I can "skip" this process?

Java code:

```
// A large text file with special characters
String text = readTextFromFile("/example/my/file.txt");
//Set the text to editText
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setText(text); //This is the line when it becomes very slow
```

XML code:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Comment: Have you set the type face somewhere?  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
myView.setTypeface(tf);  If you have special characters, this could help.

Comment: No, I did not set a typeface. Please see edit.

Comment: maybe you need to set the type face to handle special chars.

Comment: OK... But isn't the default typeface enough then? And which one should I use?

Comment: Not sure what typeface would handle your special chars (I don't even know what they are).  In our app we handle many languages and have custom font for each.  If the app can't find the characters, it doesn't know what to do with them.

Comment: @KristyWelsh I understand now. But that still doesn't explain why it is so slow, because afterwards it displays �, just like it is supposed to do.